# Keeping internal state and attaching complex child hierarchy to UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am designing a `UIViewController` extending `UITableViewDataSource` and `UITableViewDelegate`, where one of the `UITableViewCell` will have to be very complex, think the call screen of a Facetime application, where the first cell is the phone screen it self, while the other cells are information for the user.

The organization of this code smells a bit "odd", simply because I am asking a `UITableViewCell` to function as `UIViewController` with its own internal states, and maybe very complex subview hierachy. In fact the first `UITableViewCell` may contain a collection view of sorts.

Before I write any code I would like to know if this is a glaring antipattern. If so, what is a better way to design this? Keep in mind I do not know how many items will be in the parent tableview before hand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a quite common use case in the apps I've worked on. Most common use case is having a TableViewCell which contain a CollectionView controller for horizontally scrolling carousels in a list. (Similar to Netflix, AppStore apps.)

One important thing to consider is how easy/feasible it is to restore the state of the TableViewCell and it's content during recycling. This might be tricky if the TableViewCell contains for example a streaming video player.